# Error in getting image from Graph API in spring-boot with resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I am using the graph api:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
```

to get the particular user's profile photo with my access token. In postman I am able to see the image using the above get call.
In my spring-boot application I am using like below:

```
final ResponseEntity<Object> profilePicture = restTemplate.exchange(graphUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>((header)), new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
```

I am getting below error:

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [image/jpeg]
```

I have defined RestTemplate like:

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try to use `byte[]` instead of `Object` in `ParameterizedTypeReference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an appropriate `MessageConverter` to your `RestTemplate`.

Something like:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
 
 ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(graphUrl, 
 HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>((header)), byte[].class);
```

You can read more on this subject here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html

Comment: Thank you, I was trying with Byte[].